# link to download the appropriate driver nvidia-Ion 2

Tags: drivers

I have a ASUS laptop model n2015 and has also built video card - nvidia-Ion 2
   Shipping Can anyone direct me to a link to download the appropriate driver nvidia-Ion 2
   Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: But no one helped me

Comment: What drivers are you offered to install in the Additional Drivers window?

Comment: That's because no such link exist. Drivers are included with your Ubuntu. If you have problems, then ask a question - "I have such and such computer, installed such and such Ubuntu and instead of A happening B - how can I make it A?" Instead, you kinda made a decision that you need to download drivers and ask a very narrow question - and there is no good answer because the question is wrong.

Comment: @user30826 You only waited 10 hours before posting again. Please do not create multiple posts asking the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Installing an Nvidia driver manually in Linux is rather complex. Go for it only if feeling very bored, brave and adventurous. Otherwise, use the howto for everyone else.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Right! I have a laptop from Asus 12.1 inch sample n1215 and has Intel's card
  intel 3150 and Ion 2 of the integrated nvidia installed it with the new Ubuntu and I found
  Driver for Ion 2, and I'm stuck if the graphics flickering

Comment: What does it have to do with the original question? If related, you should have posted that info right away, and specify how it is related. If the problem is with the hybrid graphics, then search for, or ask a question related to the hybrid graphics, preferably in a non-vague language.

Comment: Nvidia driver lon 2 for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[32-bit](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86/285.05.09/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-285.05.09.run&lang=us&type=GeForce)

[64-bit](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/285.05.09/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-285.05.09.run&lang=us&type=GeForce)

Comment: Thank you finally someone who helps and gives a link to ... I downloaded but the installation is opening a notebook Liat
Lists through which application I should install the driver maybe I would have to download something Markt will open the file?

Comment: You need to read the [ReadMe.](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/285.05.09/README/index.html) Specifically the [installation instructions.](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/285.05.09/README/installdriver.html)