# Can someone get me a link to download the The driver of nvidia-Ion 2 Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [link to download the appropriate driver nvidia-Ion 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72629/link-to-download-the-appropriate-driver-nvidia-ion-2)

Can someone get me a link to download the
The driver of nvidia-Ion 2 Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Do not ask the same question many times please: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72629/link-to-download-the-appropriate-driver-nvidia-ion-2